# German language support not fully installed in Kubuntu 20.04 after installation

Tags: kubuntu, language-support

After installation of Kubuntu 20.04 with German install settings I noticed that parts of the system are still in English:

a) Right-click on Desktop shows English menus
b) Dolphin is in English
c) Discover is in English.
d) Login screen has English button labels

This all, eventhough I chose German in the regional settings as the only language. I even removed English there.

Why does it happen and how can I clean this mess globally and set all to German?

Comment: If the German string translations are incomplete, then there isn't anything we can do about it. We publish lots of stuff with incomplete translations. You should be able to check the translation status of any langauge for any package via launchpad.

Comment: No. I have a different laptop with Kubuntu 20.04 and there I have these system parts all in German. So there is something missing. How to reset it? Normally I get a dialog that the language suppot ist incoplete and Kubuntu installs it. But here on the new machine (Intel NUC) I was not asked.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the output of this command: `cat /etc/default/locale`

Comment: sorry, it seems that during the initial installation the language wa snot installed fully. Maybe because of missing Internet connection. I installed everything from scratch and the German language is there. Thank you for your help!